# Solve recurrence relation for non trivial base case

Tags: recurrence-relations

As per the title, I'm having some trouble to solve the recurrence equation

### Edited

$$ T(N) = 2T \left(\left\lceil \frac{N+1}{2} \right\rceil\right) +  2T \left(\left\lfloor \frac{N+1}{2} \right\rfloor\right)$$
 which is true for $N > 4$. I have two base cases, $T(3) = 6$ and $T(4) = 18$, but I'm stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Your base cases are contradictory. $T(3)=4T(2)$ and $T(4)=4T(2)$ so $T(3)=T(4)$ but this is not true.

Comment: Yeah, sorry it's fine now.

Comment: You mentioned $n^2 \ln n$, are you interested in the asymptotic behavior of $T(n)$? It is in fact $\Theta(n^2)$ by the master theorem.

Comment: @Maxim thanks, it is surely better than nothing. But it could be great to also show the exact solution (constants throws in) or at least an approximation of it. Of course I'm also interested in the explanation (which in the case of master theorem is obvious).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the simplicity put $T(n)=6S(n)$ for each $n$. Then the sequence $S$ satisfies the same recurrence relation. A computed [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIvWq.png) of the function $S$ suggests that it is piecewise linear with bends at $n=2^k+1$ and $2^k+2^{k-1}+1$. Indeed, by induction we can show that $S(2^k+1)=4^{k-1}$ and $S(2^k+2^{k-1}+1)=3\cdot 4^{k-1}$ for each $k\ge 1$. Also by induction we can show that between these points $S$ is linear, that is $$S(2^k+\lambda 2^{k-1}+1)=(1+2\lambda)4^{k-1}$$ and $$S(2^k+2^{k-1}+\lambda 2^{k-1}+1)=(3+\lambda)4^{k-1}$$ for each integer $2^{k-1}\lambda$  between $0$ and $2^{k-1}$.  The found form of the function $S$ easily implies bounds $\frac {1}4\le\tfrac{S(n)}{ (n-1)^2}\le \frac 13$ (and $\tfrac 32(n−1)^2\le T(n)\le 2(n−1)^2$), for each $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for your help, I'm trying to understand your steps. Anyhow, how could one derive the asymptotic behaviour from this?

Comment: Giving therefore $\frac{3}{2}(n-1)^2 \leq T(n) \leq 2(n-1)^2$, am I right?

Comment: Well, I couldn't hope for a better bound!!! I'm still trying to figure out your method, but anyhow many thanks for your help. Would you add the last comments in your answer?

Comment: Thanks again for the help.